# ASP.NET Core WebAPI Serilog doesn't create the log on file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm creating a simple ASP.NET Core WebAPI project. I deploy this project on a real server with IIS. I changed a little bit the *Program.cs* to add *Swagger*

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Host.UseSerilog((hostContext, services, configuration) => {
    configuration.WriteTo.Console();
    configuration.WriteTo.File($"logs/Middletier-.log", 
                               rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day);
});

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
}

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();

app.UseCors("allow-all");
app.UseHsts();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

The API is quite easy

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class YeltController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<YeltController> _logger;

    public YeltController(ILogger<YeltController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _logger.LogInformation("[YeltController] Initialized");
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Get request for test");
        return Ok("Working");
    }
}
```

In Visual Studio, when I run the project, the log is created in the `logs` folder under the project directory. When I push the application on IIS in the same machine, the application doesn't write the logs.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a permission issue to me, you can follow steps:

1. Ensure the application pool identity in IIS has proper write permissions to the log folder, or use an absolute file path for logging.
2. Double-check that the specified log folder exists on the server where IIS is running and create it if needed.
3. Verify your IIS configuration to ensure it's using the correct .NET version and identity for the application pool.

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I forget to give to the `IIS_IUSRS` the permissions to write.